# ds:esi+ecx+7 ->what does it means in Assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86

what this means `ds:esi+ecx+7` in Assembly language?

Can any one explain me what this statement means ...?

```
ds:esi+ecx+7
```

did this is any variable Declaration or any thing else..

i found it in this Assembly Code

```
xor [ds:esi+ecx+7],cl
```

so please explain what actually this statement means...

Comment: What type of assembly language are you using, for which system is this written for?

Comment: Did the formatting help confuse you, or did you just not bother to read it?

Comment: this is for 32-bit x86 Family processors

Comment: this is for 32bit x86 family processors,and i want to understand how this data segment ie ds: means (Note I don't have any knowledge about this ds,esi,ecx I only know it store something memory address like things, so help me )

Comment: This should be explained by any x86 assembly reference book under "addressing modes". Which one are you using?

Comment: just explain me what this statement   ds:esi+ecx=7 do...please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ds` is a [segment](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#Segment_Registers) prefix, which refers to the data segment. the rest is plain arithmetic to get a memory address to XOR.

In plain English: the instruction says, XOR the byte at the data segment address `esi + ecx + 7` with the contents of `CL`.

Comment: You mean it is XOR'd with `cl`

Comment: PLESASE explain  me this also..->  MOVS BYTES[ES:EDI] BYTES[ESI]

Comment: @Jitendra: that copies a byte from the location pointed to by `ESI` (source) to the location pointed to by `EDI` (destination). `REP MOVS` is intrinsic `memcpy`.